# How to install pentaho community edition Server on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: pentaho

I have followed the steps in http://wiki.joanillo.org/images/1/11/Community_user_guide.pdf but I am unable to run the server

Comment: Hi and welcom, please provide more information (encontred error and other think)

Comment: Basically I am unable to find the  start-pentaho script in the /biserver-ce/ directory as per the documentation. Please help me if there is any other alternative.

Comment: Can anyone provide me all the steps to install community edition server on ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

That document refers to version 3.x of Pentaho. Current version is 8.2. The doc is out of date by several years.

There’s no folder biserver-ce anymore, it’s now called pentaho-server. The script’s name is still the same.

You will need a JDK installed (1.8 or above, and if you install Pentaho 8.2 you should use openJDK)

Answer (score 0):

i hope you have started the server, if not run this file using terminal /pentaho-server/start-pentaho.sh ....
please provide the log it will be in the path pentahoserver->tomcat->logs->catalina.out